# Using await for with streams and handling done + onError callbacks

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, stream

I am using `dart:io`'s HTTP client to download large files the following way:

```
final url = Uri.parse(fileUrl);
final request = await httpClient.getUrl(url);
final response = await request.close();
```

Then I use the `response` of type `HttpClientResponse` which implements `Stream<List<int>>`, where each emitted `List<int>` represents a chunk of the file being downloaded.

My aim is to "transform" that stream into another one and to do so, I have recently learned of `await for` + `yield` which allows to do just that:

```
Stream<Event> processResponse(HttpClientResponse response) async* {
    await for (final List<int> chunk in response) {
        yield Event.FileChunk(chunk: chunk);
    }
    yield const Event.Completed();
}
```

Initially, and before learning about `await for`, I intended to use the method `Stream<T>.listen` which takes **4 parameters**:

1. the `onData` callback for each emitted value in the stream,
2. the `onError` callback to notify errors while emitting values,
3. the `onDone` callback to notify the stream is closing and won't be emitting any new values and finally
4. the `cancelOnError` boolean parameter that is self-explaining.

By using `await for () {}`, I believe I cover #1 and #3 since I'll get all emitted values and when done, the code will leave the `await for`'s scope which should mean it's done.

But what about errors? Since these streams will be lengthy and heavy IO streams, surely there can be an IO error at any moment. How are they reported? How can I access their data in order to report those and debug if needed?

Comment: if you want to "transform" a `Stream` use `Stream.map` / `Stream.transform` methods, more here: [Methods that modify a stream](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods)

Comment: Thanks! It seems `map` does the trick because the doc says: `Error and done events are passed through unchanged to the returned stream`, which means I can catch them when I will be listening to the my transformed stream. However  it seems `StreamTransformer` will allow me more control over errors, especially if I want to wrap them in custom error handling way.

Comment: thats absolutely right: `StreamTransformer` is more powerful but in practice `Stream.map` is good enough (actually `map()`, `expand()` and some other `Stream` methods could be implemented with a custom `StreamTransformer` but they exist as convenience methods)

Comment: Yes you are right, the documentation do say so. I'll try with `StreamTransformer` and see if I can achieve the custom error handling way I am looking for. Truth be told, I have a `Result` class that acts like a Kotlin sealed class where it is either a success or a failure (borrowed from `SealedUnions` package). Each time an even is fired, I'd like to wrap it in `Result.Success` if everything is OK otherwise yield a `Result.Failure` with more details about what went wrong (error message & code + stacktrace).

Comment: `StreamTransformer.fromHandlers` is your friend then

Answer (score 0):

Just use good ol' try catch, see this reduced example:

```
Stream<int> inee()async*{
  try{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      if(i==4)throw Exception('Hated number 4');
   yield i;
  }
  
  }catch(e,st){
    print('Catch exception $e');
    yield 33;
  }  finally{
    //cleanup of incomplete files
  }
}
void main() {
inee().listen(print);
}
```

The output would be the following:

```
0
1
2
3
Catch exception Exception: Hated number 4
3
```

inside the catch you can still yield, log your exceptions . You can also add the logic to delete incomplete files to the `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks for you answer however there is something I don't understand. In your reduced sample you manually throw an exception according to a certain value which is good in case I want to throw an error myself for any reason. But what about errors I am an not responsible for? E.g: user looses internet connection while downloading => it will cause an IO error, how will it be reported? How can I catch and wrapped in custom error handling? Or will it be reported in the `onError` in the code that will listen my transformed Stream<Event>?